# R Markdown: putting figure on separate page and with landscape positioning

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am trying to insert a figure into R Markdown. I would like to make the figure an entire page and laying flat (landscape).

Here is my code:

```
# lots of text...
{r pressure, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="Fig. 1: Treatment durations...", out.width = '100%'}
knitr::include_graphics("E:/CZ/Graphs5/Again/Scam_0hrs.png")
# lots of text...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about PDF:

````
---
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{lscape}
---

# lots of text...

\begin{landscape}

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="Fig. 1: Treatment durations...", out.width = '100%'}
plot(pressure)
```

\end{landscape}

# lots of text...
````

This is the only way I know and it only works with PDFs.

Comment: Thanks. This was very helpful.